# How do I rename an activity used in CiviCase?

Tags: activities, civicase

I have this problem on CiviCRM 4.6.8 with Joomla, and reproduced on the demo server.

If I rename an activity (from Administer->Customize Data->Activity Types) used for a Timeline within CiviCase, I can't figure out how to get the activity label to update in the backend or frontend of CiviCase.  Even if I remove the activity from the timeline and try to re-add it, it uses the original name.

Is there any way to rename it without deleting the Activity type and creating a new one?

Comment: Correction: the new names do show up in the front end, when a new Case is created.  I can't get the change to show up in the CiviCase configuration area, though.

Comment: It's probably just a name vs label thing. The config files use name because that's the reason for name vs. label - when the label changes you don't have to go and change any config or code references anywhere. Pretend that the name was actually a number not a phrase - you wouldn't expect it to change if the corresponding label changed. I suppose the config screen could show both? Are you having any problems on the front-end side?

Comment: That makes sense.  Front-end seems fine, so it's just a bit confusing on the back-end if the label is changed to something completely different, and the name doesn't reflect that change.  But it's reasonable to just create a new activity if really needed for the back-end, so long as the front-end displays the changes properly (as it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue for this here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16664

Latest comment from the core team is:

> This is both hard to fix and low priority because it only affects super admins who have privileges to define case types.
>   Patches or funding would be most welcome in moving this issue forward.